# Volley locking GUI thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I've got a problem with Volley in which my app is "locking" when a Volley request is taking a long time to finish. I feel like this should be a pretty common problem, but I haven't been able to find a way to solve it.

When the response is quick, everything just works well... But when the response is long, I'm consistently seeing skipped frames.

I *think* that I've verified with my debugger that there is a separate thread being created, creating the object, and then destroying itself correctly. So that just leaves "what's holding up the main thread?"

```
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 297 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/MyApp: got response
D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 5008 ms: [ ] RequestURL
```

Here's my code:

```
public class MyDataLoader {

    MyAsyncProcessor processor;

    public MyDataLoader() {
        processor = new MyAsyncProcessor();
    }

    public void fetchData(String url) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);

        JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    // Function that's called when a response is received
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("MyApp", "got response");
                        processor.execute(response);
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Do error stuff
            }
        });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(getRequest);
    }

    private class MyAsyncProcessor extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, DataObject> {

        @Override
        protected DataObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
            //Process json here
            DataObject myDataObject = new DataObject(params[0]);
            return myDataObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DataObject myDataObject){
            //Tell the activity we're ready for display
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you resolve this? I think I'm seeing the same thing.